# Different between throw and catch in handing exception Erlang

Tags: error-handling, erlang, runtime-error, dialyzer

I have a simple code like below to test how Erlang handling exceptions. The **** reference for throw and catch.

```
-module(exception).
-export([sum/2]).
-export([is_odd/1]).

sum(A, B) ->
    case is_odd(A) of
    odd ->
        2*A+B;
    Result ->
        Result
    end.


is_odd(A) ->
    case is_integer(A) of
    true ->
        odd;
    _ -> ****({error, "Input error"})
    end.
```

When I ran dialyzer with throw, it show warning:

> exception.erl:9: The variable Result can never match since previous
>   clauses completely covered the type 'odd'

This warning can be fixed by adding

> case catch

for funtion fun/2.

When I ran dialyzer with catch, dialyzer passed sucessesful.

I wonder a bit about catch and throw. Which situation we should you throw or catch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use throw (for the ****), your function is_odd(A) will only ever return one normal value: the atom 'odd'. That's what dialyzer is telling you: the clause at line 9 (Result ->) can never match. If is_odd(A) returns a value, it must be 'odd', so the first clause will always be chosen.

If you write 'case catch is_odd(A) of ...', then any thrown exception will be caught and turned into a value. In your case, that's the tuple {error, "Input error"}. (Note that this is an "old-style" `catch Expression`, and it's generally preferred to use the modern `try ... catch ... end` instead in all new code.) Now suddenly, there are two possible values again and the clause at line 9 can also get chosen, so dialyzer will not complain.

In general, use exceptions for relatively rare conditions, and use normal return values for common things. However, sometimes it can be a good idea to use exceptions as a long jump ("nonlocal return") to get out of a deep recursion.

Comment: Hello Richard, Thank you so much. I have 2 questions about Dialyzer and don't know how to fix it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54869082/dialyzer-warnings-no-local-return-when-do-with-fun-has-no-return/54869495#54869495